# Add foreign key in my table when I have existing data in my table on remote server?

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have existing data in my Student table. Now I want to add the foreign key in it. When I try to add the foreign key with existing data it gives error "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint". If I delete all data from Student table then it adds foreign key successfully. Now I want to add foreign key without losing the data on remote server. How can I do it? I have seen various answers but did not find the solution.

**Student Table (See last two properties)**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$", 
    ErrorMessage = "Invalid name. Use letters only")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[\.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$", 
    ErrorMessage = "Invalid name. Use letters only")]
    [Display(Name = "Father Name")]
    public String FatherName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Student Picture")]
    public String ImageURL { get; set; }

    public Class Class { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Class Title")]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; } = "Active";

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 10000)]
    public int RegistrationFee { get; set; }

    public int InstalmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Instalment Instalment { get; set; }
    }
```

**Here is my Instalments table which Id I want to make FK in Student**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Instalment1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }

    public int Instalment2 { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }

    public int Instalment3 { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date3 { get; set; }

    public int Instalment4 { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date4 { get; set; }
}
```

I want the simple solution for it because in future there will be many situations where I would be changing database accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the table schema of both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have existing data, the FK must be nullable. So the FK must be of type `int?`.

If this does not suit your business logic, then you must elect a default student and edit the corresponding migration.cs file before applaying the update to the db.

Imho, the nullable solution is best in your case: adapt your business logic to live with legacy data.

Comment: Yes, you are right! You gave me the solution. But how can we further solve it? What if we want to make it non-nullable?

Comment: You'd make it nullable, populate each and every record with a valid FK, and then you can alter the table to make it non-nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to find which records are conflicting: this is where you want to enforce a foreign key but the constraint is not met.

Then fix what is wrongly set by adding the missing data or correcting the existing data.

And then you will be able to add the foreing key to the table.

For example:

If field jobId in the PERSON table is a foreign key of the JOBS table, and you have a record in the PERSON table with jobId 53 and 53 doesn't exist in the JOBS table you won't be able to run the Alter table to add the foreing key contraint.

First you have to add a job with id 53 to the JOBS table, or if the job is actually there but with a different id, correct the jobId in the PERSON table.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.